# Asp.net MVC route name with '-'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

When I create a controller called "home-solutions", the main class is changed to `home_solutionsController`. The '-' gets replaced with '_'.

```
localhost/home-solutions
```

Also, when I call localhost/home-solutions, it says "The resource cannot be found."

How do I create a controller with '-' in its name and call it?

Comment: You cant, plain and simple.

Comment: I believe that what you really want is to have the "-" as part of URL, not necessarily controller name, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have the '-' as part of your controller name.

But, if what you really need is to support `home-solutions` in the URL, you could have a custom route which maps to a certain controller (with another name), for instance:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "HomeSolutionsRoute",
            "home-solutions/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "HomeSolutions", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```